# How to count all nodes from a non binary tree in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, data-structures, tree

I am trying to work on code for a non binary tree and so far what I could make was the result from the image below.

Problem is I cannot get the total amount of all children from the tree. I can't get them to be displayed, but not the count.

Any idea on what I am missing here?

```
class Node {
    var value: String
    var children: [Node] = []
    weak var parent: Node?

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func add(child: Node) {
        children.append(child)
        child.parent = self
    }
}

let beverages = Node(value: "beveragres")
let hotBeverages = Node(value: "hot")
let coldBeverages = Node(value: "cold")
let coldCoke = Node(value: "Cold Coke")

beverages.add(child: hotBeverages)
beverages.add(child: coldBeverages)
coldBeverages.add(child: coldCoke)

extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = "\(value)"

        if !children.isEmpty {
            text += " {" + children.map {$0.description}.joined(separator: ", ") + "} "
        }
        return text
    }
}

print(beverages.children.count)
print(beverages.children)
```

And here is the output:

> 2
>   [hot, cold {Cold Coke} ]

So for all the children from the tree it should be 3.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of tree traversal? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am not an experienced programmer, still learning, so what I got from the linked documentation is that it is about many ways of doing the search on a tree. But what I would like to learn is how to count. So I am still on ground zero here.

Comment: If you do a recursive inorder traversal, you will visit each node in the tree. If you have a counter that you increment as you visit each node, when you're done the counter tells you how many nodes are in the tree. https://www.guiguan.net/leetcode-in-swift-binary-tree-inorder-traversal/ shows a binary tree traversal in Swift. You should be able to extend that to a tree that has any number of children. Rather than traversing just left and right, you write a loop that traverses all of the nodes in the `children` array.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will read the article and report back the result.